# perform compound queries in Cloud Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

when performing Cloud Firestore compound queries with `startAfter` the result seems indefinite how do I know when I get to the last item in my collection and stop rendering.

this is the code that queries the next order should incase the driver declines

```
  async function onDecline() {
   const first = firebase.firestore().collection('dummy').doc('data').collection('test')
    .orderBy('createdAt').limit(1)
  
   const snapshot = await first.get();

  const last = snapshot.docs[snapshot.docs.length - 1]

  const next = firebase.firestore().collection('dummy').doc('data').collection('test')
    .orderBy('createdAt').startAfter(last.data().createdAt).limit(1)

   next.get().then((snapshot) => {

    let items = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
    const data = doc.data();
    const id = doc.id;

    setType(data.type)

     return{id, ...data }
   })
  console.log(items)
  setNewOrder(items);
})
  }
```

when the app loads for the first time before the driver takes any action I check for new orders in the `useEffect()` with this code

```
 firebase.firestore().collection('dummy').doc('data').collection('test')
  .orderBy('createdAt').limit(1)
  .get().then((snapshot) => {

    if(!snapshot.empty){
      let items = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
        const data = doc.data();
        const id = doc.id;

        setType(data.type)

  return{id, ...data }
 })
 // console.log(items)
 setNewOrder(items);
    }else{
      console.log('data is empty')
      setNewOrder()
    }
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

> how do I know when I get to the last item in my collection and stop rendering

You have to keep paginating documents until you receive no more.  There is no other flag or signal for the end of the result set.

Comment: then I think something is wrong with my code because keep getting result each time non stop

Answer (score 0):

The problem **might** be here:

```
startAfter(last.data().createdAt)
```

If you have multiple documents with the same value for `createdAt`, this clause is not going to necessarily giving you the correct cursor document.

Instead, consider passing the entire document to the `startAfter`, so that Firestore can use the full information in there to find the cursor document:

```
startAfter(last)
```

---

**Update**: the problem is in where you call `setNewOrder(items);`, which is outside of the `then` block that actually sets `items`. If you use `then()` any code that depends on the values in the `snapshot` needs to be inside that same `then` block.

A simpler solution is to not mix `then` and `await` as you're just making it harder for yourself an others to see what's going on. By just using `await`, the code looks like this:

```
async function onDecline() {
  const col = firebase.firestore().collection('dummy').doc('data').collection('test');
  const first = col.orderBy('createdAt').limit(1)
  const snapshot = await first.get();
  const last = snapshot.docs[snapshot.docs.length - 1]

  const next = col.orderBy('createdAt').startAfter(last).limit(1)
  const snapshot2 = await next.get()

  let items = snapshot2.docs.map(doc => { return { doc.id, ...doc.data() }; });

  console.log(items)
  setNewOrder(items);
})
```

A minimal repro in case you are having trouble making it work: https://stackblitz.com/edit/firestore-v9-compat-pagination

Comment: this still behaves same way and after careful observations I feel it's same data that is being re rendered and it doesn't move to the next one. I just added more details to my question

Comment: There's another mistake in how you handle the asynchronous behavior of the second `get()` call. I added an update, but make sure to spend time reading up on asynchronous APIs, the difference between using `then` and `await` for control, and why not to combine them.

Comment: some how this does not work for me still. it only returns the second item repeatedly

Comment: First up: did the explanation of the problem I gave in my answer make sense? And does it make sense how the code I showed then would address the problem? --- Second: if you check the StackBlitz link I provided, does that show the correct documents for you too? --- If both are yes, the problem is more likely in your implementation, which I can't see. Consider creating a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on StackBlitz like the one I shared in my answer - so that we can check there.

Comment: your explanation makes sense to me. I even copied your code but in my code `doc.id` returns an error so I had to add`...` to it so it looks like this `...doc.id` and when I test the code it still returns the second item in the database repeatedly

Comment: And on my second question: if you check the StackBlitz link I provided, does that show the correct documents for you too?